# win 10: how to "snap out" a window with the keyboard

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, windows-snap-assist

The (win + an arrow) shortcut on win 10 snapped the window to the right/left/top/bottom of the screen.
Is there a shortcut to go back to, that is, making the snapped window displayed all over the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press *Win + Up arrow* to snap the Window up. And then press it again to maximize the window.

And now to do it in a shortcut way, just press the up arrow twice while holding down the Win key. This should directly take the Window snapped to a side to its maximized state.

Answer (score 0):

To `maximize` a windows you can use `Alt + Space + x`.

Comment: For me it's `Alt` + `Space` + `N`